# Add Tracking Code in Gmap view ?

Tags: 7, google-maps, google-analytics

I have a view white a gmap and foreach Marker a link with tel number.

And I want add tracking code on this link.

I add class on my link like this:

```
<div class="gmap-popup">
   <h3>Marker Title</h3>
   <p>Description marker</p>
   <a href="tel:0000" class="js-track-phone-gmap">Call us</a>
</div>
```

And after try with jquery

```
   $('.js-track-phone-gmap').on('click', function () {
       alert('ok');
    })
```

But nothing.

Someone has already tried to add ga code on Gmap ?

Thx for your help :)

Comment: Is this a view? Or how is the Google map built/shown? Any modules used for the functionality?

Comment: Is your jQuery being loaded correctly?

Comment: Solution was found in this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/25610524